# Extension of the Schur product theorem to operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, positive-semidefinite, hadamard-product, integral-operators

Given two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, define their Hadamard product $A\circ B$ as the element-wise product, i.e.
$$(A\circ B)_{ij} = A_{ij}B_{ij}\,.$$
A well known result is the Schur product theorem, stating that if both $A$ and $B$ are non-negative defined matrices, then $A\circ B$ too is non-negative.

Is it possible to somehow extend this result to integral operators on a Hilbert space?

For instance let us consider two real functions $a,b:[0,1]^2\to \mathbb{R}$. Let's assume that they're both continuous and symmetric (i.e. $a(x,y) = a(y,x)$ and the same for $b$).

Then we can define two compact self-adjoint integral operators $A$ and $B$ on $L^2([0,1])$, by
$$A\phi(x) = \int_0^1 a(x,y)\phi(y)dy\,;\qquad B\phi(x) = \int_0^1 b(x,y)\phi(y)dy \,.$$
Let $A\circ B$ be the integral operator given by
$$(A\circ B)\phi(x) = \int_0^1 a(x,y)b(x,y)\phi(y)dy\,.$$

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are non-negative, i.e. for all $\phi$ $\langle A\phi,\phi\rangle\geq 0$ and $\langle B\phi,\phi\rangle\geq 0$.

Can we state that $A\circ B$ is non-negative?

At least, is it the case when $A$ and $B$ commute, so that they have a common orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can indeed say that $A \circ B$, as you've defined it, is a non-negative operator. Here's an adapted version of the proof outlined in the introduction to section 7.5 of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* (second edition), which is the section about the Schur product (AKA Hadamard product) theorem for matrices:

> It is a classical result (Mercer's thoerem) that if $a(x,y)$ is a continuous positive semidefinite kernel on $[0,1]$, then there exist positive real numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots$ (known as "eigenfunctions") such that
> $$
> a(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\phi_i(x)\bar\phi_i(y)}{\lambda_i} \quad \text{on } [0,1] \times [0,1]
> $$
> and the series converges absolutely and uniformly.
>
> If $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$ are both continuous positive semidefinite kernels on $[0,1]$, then $b$ also has an absolutely and uniformly convergent representation
> $$
> b(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\psi_i(x)\bar\psi_i(y)}{\mu_i} \quad \text{on } [0,1] \times [0,1]
> $$
> with all $\mu_i > 0$. The (pointwise) product kernel $a(x,y)b(x,y)$ has the representation
> $$
> a(x,y)b(x,y) = \sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \frac{\phi_i(x)\psi_j(x)\bar\phi_i(y)\bar \psi_j(y)}{\lambda_i\mu_j} \quad \text{on } [0,1] \times [0,1],
> $$
> which also converges absolutely and uniformly. Then
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \langle f, (A \circ B)f \rangle 
> &= 
> \int_{0}^1 \int_0^1 f(x) a(x,y)b(x,y)f(y)\,dy\,dx
> \\ & = 
> \sum_{i,j = 1}^\infty \frac 1{\lambda_i \mu_j} \left|\int_0^1 \phi_i(x) \psi_j(x)f(x)\,dx \right|^2 \geq 0,
> \end{align}
> $$
> so that $A \circ B$ is non-negative. This is another instance of the Schur product theorem.

---

Here's an alternative proof:

Define the operator $A \otimes B: L^2([0,1]^2)$ such that for all $f,g \in L^2[0,1]$, the element $f_1 \otimes f_2$ defined by $f_1 \otimes f_2(x_1,x_2) := f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)$ is mapped as follows:
$$
(A\otimes B)(f_1 \otimes f_2)(x_1,x_2) = \int_{0}^1\int_0^1 a(x_1,y_1)b(x_2,y_2)f_1(y_1)f_2(y_2)\,dy_1\,dy_2.
$$
In other words, taking $k(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) = a(x_1,y_1)b(x_2,y_2)$, $A \otimes B$ is simply the map
$$
(A \otimes B) f(x) = \int_{[0,1]^2}k(x,y)f(y)\,dy, \quad x,y \in \Bbb R^2.
$$
Because $L^2([0,1]^2)$ is spanned by elements of the form $f_1 \otimes f_2$, we can quickly see that $A \otimes B$ must be non-negative.

With that established: we note that
$$
\int_{0}^1 \int_0^1 f(x) a(x,y)b(x,y)f(y)\,dy\,dx = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\mu(D_n)^2} \int_{D_n}\int_{D_n} k(x,y) (f \otimes f)(x)\,dx\,dy,
$$
where $D_n \subset [0,1]^2$ is defined by $D_n = \{(x_1,x_2) : |x_1 - x_2| \leq 1/n\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and the detailed answer